# .NET - How to debug a DLL? 

Tags: asp.net, debugging, dll

I need to debug a class library project that is provided to the main project (an ASP.NET website) as a DLL. For example, I need to put some breakpoints in order to check what's happening during the execution.

I tried *[How to: Debug from a DLL Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/605a12zt.aspx)*, unfortunately it didn't work...

How can I do it?

PS: I have the source code!

Comment: And you dont have the source code of the DLL or is it a .NET library?

Comment: @GordonB I can't do that. I need to run it as an external assembly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Debugging DLLs in Visual Studio](http://www.gowland.ca/debugging-dlls-in-c)* (see #2 in the list) may be what you're looking for (full disclosure: Yes, this is my personal web site).

- With method #1, you can't watch variables.
- With method #2, step #2, if you can't open the project in the same Visual Studio instance, you can run the binary of the project (that is, run it outside of Visual Studio, but make sure you run the debug version.) and attach the Visual Studio debugger to it (menu *Debug* -> *Attach to Process*).

Here are the steps for method #2 so no one has to follow the link:

Attaching a using process to the DLL project. This involved hooking the Visual Studio debugger into a running process.

1. Open the DLL project in Visual Studio.
2. Run an application that uses the DLL. This
   application can't be run from
   another instance of Visual Studio since the
   process will already have a debugger
   attached to it.
3. From here you can add breakpoints and step through
   the DLL code loaded in Visual Studio (although
   the breakpoint will appear disabled
   the same as in method 1).

Comment: Question please. I've tried the #1 and it showed me the stack trace but how can I do if I want to watch my variables? 
I didn't understand the #2. How can I run the project that uses the DLL in the same instance of visual studio where the DLL project is loaded ?

Comment: Ok. But I have an ASP .NET project so there is no binary file!

Comment: @Amokrane, I have no experience with ASP, but there must be some executable calling the DLLs.  Can you attach to that and see what happens?

Answer (score 9):

If you have the source code, and the .pdb files in your BIN directory, then you can debug through that code. However, You will need to enable external code debugging in Visual Studio.

You need to uncheck the "Enable Just My Code" option: menu *Tools* --> *Options* --> *Debugging* --> *Enable Just My Code*

**NOTE:** This will only work for [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) assemblies.

Comment: If you have the PDB files and the source files, then all you need to do is set a breakpoint somewhere in your code that calls into the external assembly. Visual Studio will automatically pick up the symbols and load them, allowing you to step into the code. If you don't have source files then there are programs that can rebuild a representation of the code from the PDB. If you don't have the .pdb files, then things get much more difficult.

Comment: @Amokrane: you will have to step into the code. Place a debugger into your code on a place before you call some methods from the DLL. Step into the method by pressing F11.

Comment: @Josh Where is this pdb file located? Inside the debug directory?
@Marek When I do that it tells me: There is no source code available for the current location

Comment: Turns out I have them. But stepping through the code is impossible :(

Comment: As long as the PDB files are located right next to your assembly in the debug folder, it should load the symbols. If this doesn't happen then you can load them manually while debugging by going to Debug > Windows > Modules ---- Right click on the DLL and select Load Symbols From > File Path

Answer (score 0):

When you build the class library project, the .pdb file is created in the `Debug` or `Release` folder of that class library. These two file are referred to  by the [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) project when you right click and select the option "Add a Reference" and point to the DLL file of the class library project.