# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float' - Prettytable Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, prettytable

I'm getting the above error trying to run my Py script. It also throws error in the prettytable code which is weird, as well, since I use it fine all the time. This is basically a web-scraping script that I made for use with an airline manager game I play.

Code:

```
if "top" in str(r): # log-in was successful.
   if True: # just to make it collapsible
    def getHTML(url):
        return http.request('GET', url, headers={'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID='+phpSid}).data

    def findBetween1(s, start, end):
        try:
            return str((s.split(start))[1].split(end)[0])
        except:
            return ""

    def getHTMLthreaded(infoArray): # infoArray: [url, detail, detail]
        def getHTML(url):
            return http.request('GET', url, headers={'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID='+phpSid}).data

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as executor:
            futureToURL = {executor.submit(getHTML, info): info for info in infoArray}
            responseResults = []
            for future in as_completed(futureToURL):
                responseResults.append(future.result()) # [data, url]

        return responseResults

    def median(lst):
        lst = [int(i) for i in lst]
        n = len(lst)
        s = sorted(lst)
        return int((sum(s[n//2-1:n//2+1])/2.0, s[n//2])[n % 2]) if n else None

acURLs = []
fleet = BeautifulSoup(getHTML('https://www.airline4.net/fleet.php?undefined'), "lxml").find_all(onclick=re.compile('Ajax')) # get a list of fleet

for acTypeId in fleet:
    acURLs.append('https://www.airline4.net/fleet.php?type='+findBetween1(str(acTypeId), 'type=', "'")) # for each fleet type, get a list of aircraft belonging to that type

acMenus = getHTMLthreaded(acURLs)

# t = PrettyTable([])
acIds = []
for acMenu in acMenus:
    acMenuItems = BeautifulSoup(acMenu, "lxml").find_all(onclick=re.compile('routes_main.php'))
    for thisAcMenu in acMenuItems:
        acIds.append('https://www.airline4.net/fleet_details.php?id='+findBetween1(str(thisAcMenu['onclick']), 'id=', "','"))

# acIds = ['https://www.airline4.net/fleet_details.php?id=1323552']

print('Sorting by "profit/pax", indicating how well the route actually profits.')
t = PrettyTable(['model', 'reg', 'chkH', 'wear', 'config', 'fn', 'route', u'$\u02dc', u'CO\u2082\u02dc', 'fuel', 'prof/pax', 'prof/hrs'])

acDetails = getHTMLthreaded(acIds)
for acDet in acDetails:
    acDet = BeautifulSoup(acDet, "lxml")

    mainTable = acDet.find(class_='col-sm-6 bg-light border').find_all(class_='m-text')
    seatLayout = acDet.find_all(class_='col-4 p-2 text-center exo')

    acType = str(mainTable[0].string)
    fleetReg = str(acDet.find(id='ff-name').string)
    chk = str(mainTable[2].string) # hours to check
    wear = str(mainTable[6].string) # wear percentage
    yS = str(seatLayout[0].find('br').next_sibling.strip().rjust(3))
    jS = str(seatLayout[1].find('br').next_sibling.strip().rjust(3))
    fS = str(seatLayout[2].find('br').next_sibling.strip().rjust(3))
    config = yS + "/" + jS + "/" + fS
    try: # in case the aircraft is not routed:
        routeReg = str(acDet.find(id='rr-name').string)
        stop = str(acDet.find(class_='xs-text pt-2')).replace('<div class="xs-text pt-2">Via<br/> ','').replace('</div>','')
        stop = "" if stop == "None" else "·" + stop
        route = str(acDet.find_all(class_='l-text exo')[0].string) + stop + "·" + str(acDet.find_all(class_='l-text exo')[1].string)

        inc, co2 = [], []
        for thisFlight in acDet.find_all(class_='row bg-light m-text p-1 border'):
            inc.append(str(thisFlight.find(class_='col-3 text-right text-success').find('b').string).replace('$', '').replace(',', ''))
            co2.append(str(thisFlight.find(class_='s-text').string).replace(' Quotas', '').replace(',', ''))
            prices = thisFlight.find_all(class_='col-3')[2]

        inc, co2 = median(inc), median(co2)
        fuel = str(acDet.find(class_='row bg-light m-text p-1 border').find_all(class_='s-text')[1].string).replace(' Lbs', '').replace(',', '')
        profit = inc - (co2 * co2Price / 1000) - (int(fuel) * fuelPrice / 1000)

        depTime = acDet.find_all(class_='col-6 bg-white border s-text')[0].string.strip().replace(' UTC', '').split(':')
        arrTime = acDet.find_all(class_='col-6 bg-white border s-text')[1].string.strip().replace(' UTC', '').split(':')

        depSec = int(depTime[0])*3600 + int(depTime[1])*60 + int(depTime[2])
        arrSec = int(arrTime[0])*3600 + int(arrTime[1])*60 + int(arrTime[2])
        hrsElapsed = ((86400 - (depSec - arrSec)) if depSec > arrSec else arrSec - depSec) / 3600

        profPax = round(profit / (int(yS) + int(jS)*2 + int(fS)*3),3)
        profHrs = round(profit / hrsElapsed, 3)

        t.add_row([acType, fleetReg, chk, wear, config, routeReg, route, inc, co2, fuel, profPax, profHrs])
    except: # only show the fleet details, but no other metrics
        # print(sys.exc_info()[0])
        t.add_row([acType, fleetReg, chk, wear, config, "", "", "", "", "", "", ""])

t.sortby = 'prof/pax'
print(t)

else:
print('Your e-mail and/or password was wrong.')
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dX.py", line 123, in <module>
    print(t)
  File "C:\Users\SSM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\prettytable.py", line 237, in __str__
    return self.__unicode__()
  File "C:\Users\SSM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\prettytable.py", line 243, in __unicode__
    return self.get_string()
  File "C:\Users\SSM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\prettytable.py", line 984, in get_string
    rows = self._get_rows(options)
  File "C:\Users\SSM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\prettytable.py", line 933, in _get_rows
    rows.sort(reverse=options["reversesort"], key=options["sort_key"])
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

Comment: please provide the full error traceback

Comment: @TinNguyen Hey, I've added the traceback to the post.

Comment: Your last action, after throwing an error, is to add a lot of empty strings to the table that you sort. Therefore the error: is the *number* `0.5` less than, equal to, or greater than the *string* `''`? You could argue for an answer but the short answer is: Python does not support such a comparison.

Comment: For future reference: please don't post whole programs. The BeautifulSoup part doesn't throw this error. A small data set that causes the same issue would have let us help you too. In *this specific case* the traceback was sufficient for us to help out but that's not always the case and asking experts that might help you to run your huge chuck of code is going to put up barriers and delay help.

Comment: In actual fact, your code requires a login that we won't have. Try to narrow down problems by trying to run the code with only half of what is going on still in place (with an intermediary result saved in a variable). Once you figure out in what part of the program the problem lies, find a way to give us what's in the intermediate variable without all the work that went before it. Replace it with dummy data, for example.

Comment: As it stands, I can't now offer further advice or help because I can't run this code and see what other issues there might be lurking below the surface, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

When you are handling an exception, you add a default value that can't be compared with your floating-point numbers:

```
except:
    t.add_row([acType, fleetReg, chk, wear, config, "", "", "", "", "", "", ""])
    #                       these are all strings   ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^
```

If you want to sort on the `prof/pax` column, you'd have to give that column *only numeric values*. Perhaps `0` would suffice for you?

```
except:
    t.add_row([acType, fleetReg, chk, wear, config, "", "", "", "", "", 0, ""])
    #                                        numeric value for profPax ^^
```

Alternatively, you can specify a *sort key*, called to transform each value in the sorted column to something to compare by. You could use that to replace strings with zeros *only when sorting*:

```
t.sort_key = lambda value: value or 0
```

This makes use of the fact that both `""` and `0` are false-y and so `or` will pick the second value to return, `0`:

```
>>> value = ""
>>> value or 0
0
```

Side note: it is *rarely* a good idea to use `except:` without qualification. If your code has, say, zero-division issues, *only catch that exception*:

```
except ZeroDivisionError:
     t.add_row([acType, fleetReg, chk, wear, config, "", "", "", "", "", "", ""])
```

You can always add more exceptions; your code could potentially raise `ValueError`s (from `int()` conversions and the like) and `AttributeError` (from trying to treat `None` values as if they are BeautifulSoup elements, for example), so you could catch *only those 3*:

```
except (ZeroDivisionError, ValueError, AttributeError):
     t.add_row([acType, fleetReg, chk, wear, config, "", "", "", "", "", "", ""])
```

That makes it a lot easier to detect bugs in your code later on, and would let you more easily interrupt your program if it is taking to long as you are then not catching the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception.

Comment: Testing comment helper: [.NET - How to debug a DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2622250)